# Remove class of image with specific data value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want remove a class of images with specific data. I am using:

```
var end_foto = 'http://somesite.com/image.jpg';
$('img[data-url]="'+end_foto+'"').removeClass('thumb-selecionado');
```

But it returns:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:img[data-url]="http://somesite.com/image.jpg"
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need `]` in last like below:-

```
var end_foto = 'http://somesite.com/image.jpg';
$('img[data-url="'+end_foto+'"]').removeClass('thumb-selecionado');
```

The selector structure need to be `img[data-url="abc"]`

Example:-

```js
var end_foto = 'http://somesite.com/image.jpg';
$('img[data-url="'+end_foto+'"]').removeClass('thumb-selecionado');
```

```css
.thumb-selecionado{
  width;50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple/v4/e0/9d/64/e09d64ec-b4f1-5e55-3599-308e29d5a94d/source/100x100bb.jpg" data-url = "http://somesite.com/image.jpg" class="thumb-selecionado"><br/><br/>
<img src="http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple/v4/e0/9d/64/e09d64ec-b4f1-5e55-3599-308e29d5a94d/source/100x100bb.jpg" data-url = "http://somesite.com/image1.jpg" class="thumb-selecionado"><br/><br/>
```

Comment: @PedroAntônio  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

You have the selector structured wrong. It should look like this:-

```
$('img[data-url="'+end_foto+'"]').removeClass('thumb-selecionado');
```

Comment: Yeah, i close the brackets prematurely. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep, anytime. Happy coding